# Zend Form File upload won't validate or upload files

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I'm trying to do a file upload with Zend Form, but I just cannot get file uploads to work.

Here's my form code:

```php
public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($options);
        $this->setName('modelupload');
        $this->setMethod('post');
        $this->setAction('/model/upload');
        $this->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');

        // ... other elements ... //

        $file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');
        $file
            ->setAttrib('title', 'Select a file to upload.')
            ->setAttrib('required',"")
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addValidator('Count',false,1)
            ->addValidator('Size',false,104857600)
            ->setMaxFileSize(104857600)
            ->setValueDisabled(true)
            ->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH . "/../data/models/temp/")
            ->setLabel('Select a file to upload.');

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit', array(  
            'label' => 'Upload'  
        ));
        $submit->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');

        $this->setDecorators( array( array('ViewScript',
        array('viewScript' => 'formViews/_form_upload_model.phtml'))));

        $this->addElements(array($name, $description, $file, $submit));
    }
```

And here is my controller code:

```php
public function uploadAction()
{
    // action body
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $this->view->pageTitle = "Model Upload";

    $form = new Application_Model_FormModelUpload();

    if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->_request->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
            echo "<h1>Valid</h1>";

            $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();
            $files  = $upload->getFileInfo();

            $form->getValues();

        } else {
            echo "<h1>Not Valid</h1>";
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($formData);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

And then when I try and upload something, I get this:

```php
Not Valid
Array
(
    [name] => title
    [description] => description
    [MAX_FILE_SIZE] => 104857600
    [file] => filename.extension
    [submit] => Upload
)
```

I.e the form is *not* passing validation and I have no idea why. Aside from this, the file *isn't* being uploaded. I've tried so many things and now I'm at my wit's end. I'm using Zend server CE on my local environment if that makes any difference.

I thank anyone in advance for any help they can offer!

## EDIT:

Tried MIss poo's code below and got this:

```php
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
        )

    [description] => Array
        (
        )

    [file] => Array
        (
        )

    [submit] => Array
        (
        )

)
Array
(
)
```

Absolutely no errors being returned...

Comment: What is a form validation error message?

Comment: There are no error messages, that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issee, when I removed `setMaxFileSize(104857600)` from my form I got error    `[fileUploadErrorIniSize] => File 'image' exceeds the defined ini size`, so i had to change my php.ini config and add this to my form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get that where your validation is being fail.

```
if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
  //you code
} else {
   print_r($form->getMessages()); //error messages
   print_r($form->getErrors()); //error codes
   print_r($form->getErrorMessages()); //any custom error messages
}
```

This will trace that where your validation is going to fail and then you can easily solve it.
That might at least give you a better idea of 'why'.

Comment: This doesn't validate, i.e. goes through to the else, but when I print_r all those things, the arrays are all empty. I've added the result to the question above.

Comment: @HarryMustoe-Playfair what is this `$form = new Application_Model_FormModelUpload();` ? is this your model or form?

Comment: it is my form model, i.e. it is declared as thus: `class Application_Model_FormModelUpload extends Zend_Form { //...`

Comment: @HarryMustoe-Playfair in the else part please check `print_r($form->populate($formData));` . may be this will give some result.

Answer (score 0):

try the [Zend_File_Transfr_Adapte_Http](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.1/classes/Zend.File.Transfer.Adapter.Http.html) here's an example :

```
    if ($this->_request->isPost()) {

        $formData = $this->_request->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
            echo "<h1>Valid</h1>";

            /* Uploading Document File on Server */
            $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
            $upload->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH . "/../data/models/temp/");

            try {
                 // upload received file(s)
             $upload->receive();
            } catch (Zend_File_Transfer_Exception $e) {
             $e->getMessage();
            }

       } else {
            echo "<h1>Not Valid</h1>";
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($formData);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

.